# Can the content of a plain-text help breaking the key to the encryption used?

Tags: encryption, aes, file-encryption, defense

i am currently trying to encrypt a set of files safely (using AES encryption in CBC mode), but knowing that plain text copies of some of these files may be floating around the file system i am worried that the content of these copied files can help break the key to the entire set of files i am trying to encrypt (with the same key). i know a very obvious solution is to encrypt every file with it's own key but, it seems quite an awkward solution...

Comment: The only benefit to an attacker would be not having to compute a plaintext analysis for each key during a bruteforce. Otherwise, this is designed to specifically be strong against this attack. I'd suggest looking at "chosen plaintext attacks".

Comment: i guess brute forcing a 256 bit key would be quite time consuming....

Answer (score 0):

No, knowing the plaintext of a given ciphertext does not improve an attackers attempt to break AES-CBC.

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks